# How safe is sending in functions to String.replace?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a string resolver function and I want it to take an object to resolve all "<%=variable%>" occurrences. I have the ability to set some of the object properties to functions and have those functions return values automatically. Is this safe? I originally planned on parsing out the tokens and getting return values from functions based on what I parsed from the token. Having String.replace do it seems a lot easier but I am not sure what the security risks are. Any ideas or comments? This will mainly be used in node.js so I don't imagine any user access to the function.

```
    var data = {
        name: "Mike",
        job: "programmer"
    },
    funcs = {
        date: function () {return new Date;},
        timestamp: function () {return new Date().getTime();},
        guid: function () {return "4FGGX3g";}
    };
    function resolve (str,resolvers) {
    var regex,result;
    result = str;

    str.match(/(<%=.+?%>)/g).forEach(function (item) {
        var token,itr,resolver;
        token = item.split(/(\w+)/)[1];
        for (itr = 0; itr < resolvers.length; itr += 1) {
            resolver = resolvers[itr][token];
            if (resolver) {
                regex = new RegExp(item,'g');
                result = result.replace(regex,resolver);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
    }
    console.log(resolve("My name is <%=name%> and I am a <%=job%>.\nThe date is: <%=date%>\nTimestamp: <%=timestamp%>\nUniqieID: <%=guid%>",[data,funcs]));
```

Comment: *"This will mainly be used in node.js so I don't imagine any user access to the function."* Then "safety" doesn't really enter into it. Do you actually know what (if any) dangers you face? If you can't define what "unsafe" is, you can't really call code "safe".

Comment: Are you worried about some sort of injection attack? Does the string in `str` come directly from the user? Even if it does, how would you imagine that the user could affect security?

Comment: All strings are in server side templates. I can't think of a way that the user would be able to inject anything into the templates. Good point. thanks.